# Not showing posts where boolean is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an app I am making where users can post items and then they can select "live" when they select "live" as true the post should show up in a live tab.

Right now this is my posts_controller.rb create and update actions

```html
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
      flash[:success]="Post created"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

def update 
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   if @post.update(post_params)
   flash[:success]="Updated successfully"
   redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
 end

--------------------------------
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description,
                         :category_id, :subcategory_id, :live)
  end
```

My Post form for editing and creating a new post.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var subcat;
  subcat = $('#subcategory-select').html();
  return $('#category-select').change(function() {
    var cat, options;
    cat = jQuery('#category-select').children('option').filter(':selected').text();
    options = $(subcat).filter("optgroup[label='" + cat + "']").html();
    if (options) {
      return $('#subcategory-select').html(options);
    } else {
      return $('#subcategory-select').empty();
    }
  });
});
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @post%>
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <p>
 <%= f.label :title %><br/>
 <%= f.text_field :title, maxlength: "10" %>
  </p>
  <p>
 <%= f.label :description %><br>
 <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
 <%= f.label :category_id%>
 <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name,    
                { prompt: 'Select a category' }, { id: 'category-select' }) %>
  </p>
  <p>
 <%= f.label :subcategory_id%>
 <%= f.grouped_collection_select :subcategory_id, Category.all, :sub_categories, 
           :name, :id, :name, { include_blank: 'Select a sub category' },
                                                { id: 'subcategory-select' } %>
   </p>
   <p>
    <%= f.label :live%>
    <%= check_box_tag :live , 0 , @post.live ? false : true %> <!--work on-->
   <p>
  <p>
 <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to "Back to posts listing", posts_path %>
```

The posts doesn't save as being `live`, I can force it into being live with the rails console however. This brings me to the next issue.

I forced a `post` to have `live == true` and it doesn't show up in my bootstrap live tab. This is for my subcategory show action which is where I am trying to do this first.

```html
  def show
    @subcategory = SubCategory.find(params[:id])
    @subcategory_posts = @subcategory.posts#live posts in this subcat
    @subcategory_posts_live = (params[:live] == 'true')
  end
```

And the `show.html.erb` bootstrap navigation tabs which should show the live posts but doesn't on click

```html
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
     <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Posts</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Live ◯</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">xx</a></li>
   </ul>

   <!-- Tab panes -->
   <div class="tab-content">
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home"><%=render 'posts/post', obj: @subcategory_posts %></div>
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile"><%=render 'posts/post', obj: @subcategory_posts_live %></div>
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
   </div>
```

I know that it is looking for posts because in the view it shows `<p>No Listings found</p>` which is what I am displaying in my 'posts/_post` partial if no posts are found within that specific category i.e Live Subcategory Posts.

Unsure on how to work this one out, any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your form is missing a checkbox to allow the user to select if a post is live or not. You need a checkbox.

So something like this may work:

```
<%= f.check_box :live %>
```

To query for all posts that are live (I'm assuming this is a boolean column in your db):

```
@live_posts = Post.where(live: true)
```

For your subcategory query, you can do this:

```
@subcategory_posts = Post.where(subcategory_id: params[:id], live: true)
```

(This assumes posts have a subcategory_id column)

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for the answer it worked! Turns out i forgot to but f.check_box in my _form partial and I was using code from another answer that wasn't as simple as this, thanks a lot. The new posts saved as #<Post id: 8, title: "We live?", description: "shoutout to Ryan Doherty", category_id: 1, subcategory_id: 1, live: true, created_at: "2016-11-18 00:57:40", updated_at: "2016-11-18 00:57:40">]>  Does the bootstrap nav tabs auto ajax or do I have to code that in?

Comment: Great, glad to hear it worked! I don't have much knowledge of the bootstrap tabs stuff, so I can't really help you, sorry!